# WebStorm Angular code arrangement - put decorated variables after non decorated

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm trying to configure arrangement rules so class local variables are put before input variables.
Kinda sort them like this:

```
private x;
public y;
@Input private z;
@Input public q;
```

But I can't find any information how to achieve that.
Has anyone encountered the same impediment and found a solution to it?

Ex. transform this:

```
export class TestComponent {
    private options;
    public loading;

    @Input()
    public data;
    @Input()
    private elementId;
}
```

into this:

```
export class TestComponent {
    private options;

    public loading;

    @Input()
    private elementid;

    @Input()
    public data;
}
```

but all I managed to achieve is this:

```
export class TestComponent {
    private options;
    @Input()
    private elementId;

    @Input()
    public data;
    public loading;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible; please vote for [WEB-29658](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29658) and linked tickets to be notified on any progress with this feature